# Flutter plugin that uses an EventChannel

Tags: android, kotlin, plugins, flutter

I'm creating a flutter plugin that uses a 3rd party SDK

The SDK has an override method called onIdleTimeout(), when this method fires the SDK logs the users out, and pulls up a native login view.

I don't want this native login view to pop up, so when this onIdleTimeout() fires I want to send a message back to the Flutter dart code that is using my plugin to simply let it know that the onIdleTimeout() method has fired

I've looked at examples of using EventChannels but none of them show using event channels inside of an custom override method in native code

any help is much appreciated thank you, I'm starting with the Android/Kotlin side of the plugin so any kotlin examples would be great

Comment: Rather than using an event channel, why not just call a method on the Dart side, perhaps called `onIdleTimeout`. Implement that on the Dart side. See question 50187680

Answer (score 0):

Found out I can just use a BasicMessageChannel to send a message from native to dart